# How to scan for audio files in iOS

Tags: ios, enumeration, nsfilemanager

My app downloads a zip file from a server and extracts the contents to the device. I need a way to find all of the audio files (mp3, mp4a, m4b, etc.) It also needs to scan all the subdirectories. Right now this is what I am doing.

```
-(NSArray *)audioPathsInDirectory:(NSString *)directory {
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *enumerator =  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] enumeratorAtPath:directory];
    NSMutableArray *audioPathArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSString *partialFilePath;
    while (partialFilePath = [enumerator nextObject]) {
        if ([[partialFilePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"m4b"] ||
            [[partialFilePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"m4a"] ||
            [[partialFilePath pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"mp3"]) {
            [audioPathArray addObject:partialFilePath];
        }
    }
    return audioPathArray;
}
```

My worry is that the "isEqualToString:" parts will miss some things. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by `My worry is that the "isEqualToString:" parts will miss some things`?

There is nothing wrong with your approach but it is better convert extension using `lowercaseString` before compare to make sure it handle case sensibility.

Comment: There's more audio extensions that those three. Is there a general purpose way to just look for any type of audio?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no such thing. You can create your own helper function where you can define all the audio types that you can support. It is easy to extend, maintain and reuse.